# How Does search engines index Restful multilingual sites

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, search-engine, multilingual, seo

Im working on a multilingual site using  asp.net mvc, and im wondering how search engines will index my site if urls will be the same for all the languages e.g.:

```
mysite.com/article/25/my-first-article //for spanish
mysite.com/article/25/my-first-article //for english
```

Im controlling language set with this action:

```
public ActionResult SetCulture(string culture)
        {
            HttpContext.Session["culture"] = culture
            return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
        }
```

I control the current language using some links like:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("English", "SetCulture", new {controller = "Culture", culture = "en"})%>
<%= Html.ActionLink("Español", "SetCulture", new {controller = "Culture", culture = "es"})%>
```

Will search engines index both versions of the content?

Does this have any side effects on Page Rank?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may take a look at the [following tips](http://www.searchenginejournal.com/multilingual-seo/19903/). Here are some that should basically answer your question:

- Keep the content for each language on separate URLs
- Don't use cookies to show translated page versions

So in terms of SEO what you are doing is not good.

Answer (score 1):

Google just announced [New markup for multilingual content](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/12/new-markup-for-multilingual-content.html). This should make it easier for multi-language sites to deal with translated versions of their website.